# Consume C# event from F#

Tags: c#, events, f#

Followed [Functional Reactive Programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-reactive/) tutorial, where stream of events (`Observable`) is directly created from `System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed` event.

```
 let timer = new System.Timers.Timer(float 1)
 let observable = timer.Elapsed  
 observable 
 |> Observable.subscribe ...
```

Have `class` defined in C#

```
public delegate void OnMessageDelegate(Message message);

public class Notifier : INotifier
{
   public event OnMessageDelegate OnMessage;

   public void Notify(Message message) 
   => OnMessage?.Invoke(message);
}
```

Referenced corresponding .dll into F# project and trying to create `Observable` from `Notifier.OnMessage` event

```
 let Start (notifier : Namespace.Notifier)  = 
    notifier.OnMessage      
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun ms -> ...
    0
```

Getting error message

> The event `OnMessage` has a non-standard type. If this event is declared in another CLI language, you may need to access this event using the explicit `add_OnMessage` and `remove_OnMessage` methods for the event. If this event is declared in F#, make the type of the event an instantiation of either `IDelegateEvent<_>` or `IEvent<_,_>`.

The error message is self descriptive, though I aim to create stream from event and not to subscribe on it via `add_OnMessage` method.

Comment: What if you get rid of `OnMessageDelegate` and change `OnMessage` to `public event EventHandler<Message> Messaged;`? (N.b. both the rename and the type change are intentional.)

Comment: @ildjarn Excellent, *The event 'OnMessage' has a non-standard type* was hint in error message which i did not get. Post an answer, will accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that F# expects the delegate type for events to be `System.EventHandler` or a specialization of `System.EventHandler<'TEventArgs>`.

Try changing the type of `OnMessage` from `OnMessageDelegate` to `EventHandler<Message>`.