# How to disable the annoying Intellisense note in a class that has members with CLIEvent attributes?

Tags: wpf, f#, intellisense

Similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964348/c-style-event-accessors-for-cli-events-in-f) I have a class with some members that need to be compiled with CLIEvent handlers:

```
static let customEvent add remove =
  { new IDelegateEvent<_> with
        member this.AddHandler del = add del
        member this.RemoveHandler del = remove del }

let evKnock = customEvent (fun v -> t.AddHandler(knockEvent,v)) (fun v -> t.RemoveHandler(knockEvent,v))
let evPreviewKnock = customEvent (fun v -> t.AddHandler(previewKnockEvent,v)) (fun v -> t.RemoveHandler(previewKnockEvent,v))

[<CLIEvent>] member t.Knock = evKnock
[<CLIEvent>] member t.PreviewKnock = evPreviewKnock
```

Now in other methods whenever I type `t.` I see this sort of note in Intellisense as the first thing:

> The event 'PreviewKnock' has a non-standard type. If this event is
>   declared in another CLI language, you may need to access this method
>   using explicit add_PreviewKnock and remove_PreviewKnock for the event.
>   If this event is declared in F#, make the type of the event an
>   instantiation of either 'IDelegateEvent< _ >' or 'IEvent< _ , _ >'

Can I turn this warning off somehow? The events are of the type IDelegateEvent.

Comment: See also [Consume C# event from F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38009398/636019).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to reproduce this, but your code is not complete, so I'm not sure if this is the same behavior you are getting. However, if I modify your code slightly, I get the same error as you:

```
type A() = 
  let customEvent add remove =
    { new IDelegateEvent<_> with
          member this.AddHandler del = add del
          member this.RemoveHandler del = remove del }

  let evKnock = customEvent ignore ignore
  [<CLIEvent>] member t.Knock = evKnock
```

This seems to be because `Knock` is inferred to be of type `IDelegateEvent<System.Delegate>`.

The compiler wants you to specify a concrete delegate type - you can define your own or use a standard one from the .NET libraries. The following compiles fine:

```
type A() = 
  let customEvent add remove =
    // Explicitly specify delegate type as System.EventHandler (for example)
    { new IDelegateEvent<System.EventHandler> with
          member this.AddHandler del = add del
          member this.RemoveHandler del = remove del }

  let evKnock = customEvent ignore ignore
  [<CLIEvent>] member t.Knock = evKnock
```

Comment: As an extra note, given that I am working on a UI button control I needed to change the type to `System.RoutedEventHandler` instead to get it to work. It surprised me that there are runtime type checks for this.